# How to make Error Message Readable by JAWS

Tags: jaws-screen-reader, aria-live

I have following Error message on screen, but its not readable by JAWS version 15 screen reader.

```
<span aria-live="assertive" aria-invalid="true">
<span class="accessibleText">Error</span>Enter a valid Phone number.</span>
```

I have also tried role='alert' and aria-atomic='true'properties but its still not readable on Chrome and IE browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `role="alert"` and you need a change to the DOM (text) inside the `role="alert"` element. Use JavaScript to change the text inside the ***accessibleText*** span, or add/remove the entire span from the DOM with JavaScript.

More details here: [Jaws doesn't read error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156249/jaws-doesnt-read-error-message/41402001)

```
<span aria-live="assertive" aria-invalid="true">
<span role="alert" class="accessibleText">Error</span>Enter a valid Phone number.</span>
```